# What are the more common house rules for Cthulhutech and the Framewerk system?

Tags: house-rules, cthulhutech

Do you remember ***Cthulhutech***? I been interested in running a game inside that universe, but I have read some people saying that "***Framewerk***" is a broken system.

Framewerk is the Cthulhutech conflicts mechanics base system. I have read the books and I can't tell why people may be saying it's broken.

What are the house rules you have applied for Cthulhutech and Framewerk?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Please take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. We're not a normal discussion forum and questions where the motive is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______” are [off topic](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you have mistaken us for a discussion forum, you may wish to try [one of these instead](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449). If you can edit this to be focused on [a directly answerable question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then it might have a place here.

Comment: If you can earn 20 rep on the site, you're welcome to discuss the topic in our chat room, though this game was incredibly niche.  I'm not sure you'll find a lot of folks able to discuss it.

Comment: @Lobo7922 Quizzing people for what house rules they use is not what this site is for. It matches at least one of the types of questions to avoid asking in our [help/dont-ask].

Comment: It really seems as if you want to want to see something like a discussion happen. Up in the first comment, there is a link to outlets that are suitable for such a desire. Some of them are chat, some of them are discussion forums. We're not jealous — we're happy to see you get your question answered elsewhere, if that's what you need.